# Display background image HTML2PDF

Tags: html, css, html2pdf

I would like to convert html file into pdf format using online tools or html2pdf library. But it converts all page but not background image.

```
<STYLE type="text/css">    
    body {margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 0px;
        background-image: url(http://IP/check/form/image.jpg);
     }
</style>
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because your image is on different domain.

Comment: If sure then answer it

Comment: Its wrong assumption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing body tag background to div tag background URL solved the issue.

```
  <STYLE type="text/css">    
    #divid{margin-top: 0px;margin-left: 0px;
        background-image: url(http://****.jpg);
     }
</style>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="divid">
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the above answer really working in 2023? I have to check what script you have used for html2pdf to show background image

Answer (score 0):

now work for me.
Following the doc, First I needed to create a page tag wrapping my content.

```
<page backcolor="#FEFEFE" backimg="https://absolute-url/logo-130x90.png"  backimgw="100%" >
```

https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/blob/master/doc/page.md