# html to pdf conversion background image

Tags: php, html, pdf, yii, background-image

I am using `yii` extension to convert html to pdf and this is the html code i am using.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center; width:100%; padding:35px 0 15px 0;"><img src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/images/digest_logo.png" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center; color:#2d2d2d;">April 18, 2016</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:20px;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; background:#f3f3f1;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width:100%; padding:40px 75px 35px;">
                            <h1 style="margin:0 0 35px 0; font-weight:normal; font-size:24px;">Hi, Patron</h1>
                            <p style="margin:0 0 4px 0; font-size:17px;">Greetings from Crownit,</p>
                            <p style="margin:0 0 4px 0; font-size:17px;">Crown it believes ut is very important to. make</p>
                            <p style="margin:0 0 4px 0; font-size:17px;">Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsumhhhhhhhhh hhhhhn </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-image:url(<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl;?>/images/bg-script.png)">
                sdf
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Suddenly i stuck to a place where i want to use `background-image` as my design is something like this

[image: Image reference]

When i see the result in pdf i got this error

> Impossible to load the image C:/xampp/htdocs//var/www/html/insight/insight/images/bg-script.png

I am not sure why this background css is not working in pdf well its working fine in browser.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The unique option that works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77853463/2415632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.

This pdf extension has a very little css support.

Currently, only the following CSS attributes are supported:

- font-family
- font-size
- font-weight
- font-style
- color
- background-color
- text-decoration
- width
- height
- text-align

Other tags will not work.

Comment: What does your extension use? If its html2pdf, then you should be able to use the <page> tags and its backimg attribute to specify a background on every page. http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:page

Comment: I am using <page> tag and i know i am able to use full page background image but if you read the question carefully i asked for the background between a single heading