# How to add the seperate title and background image in html2pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf and I need to export a pdf of my page that includes the **Title**, **Background Image**, and **Content** upon clicking the export button.

I have attempted the code below, but I am only able to receive the content. Although I know I have to add the **id** of **main-content-para** within the code to export the content, I cannot do so because my content layout is different. Instead, I have to add a separate code for the title and background.

Any suggestions for how I can solve this issue?

```js
function generate() {
   let element = document.getElementById('main-content-para')
   html2pdf(element, {
      margin: 10,
      filename: 'output.pdf',
      image: {
         type: 'jpeg',
         quality: 0.98
      },
      html2canvas: {
         scale: 2,
         logging: true,
         dpi: 192,
         letterRendering: true
      },
      jsPDF: {
         unit: 'mm',
         format: 'a4',
         orientation: 'portrait'
      }
   });
}
```

```css
body, h1 {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

h1 {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   color: #fff;
}

.btn {
   padding: 08px 20px;
   font-size: 20px;
   background-color: #f00;
   color: #fff;
   text-decoration: none
}

.banner {
   background-image: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/2662116/pexels-photo-2662116.jpeg');
   height: 400px;
   width: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.8.0/html2pdf.bundle.js"></script>

<div class="banner">
   <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
</div>

<div id="main-content-para">
   <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In molestie ultricies elit vel porta. Nam pretium augue vel risus euismod tempor. Etiam nec est consectetur, tempus urna in, vestibulum quam. Sed semper elit ac ultrices condimentum. Sed efficitur
      bibendum orci. Donec vitae odio fringilla, blandit ante auctor, rhoncus est. Suspendisse accumsan ex nec lacus sagittis pharetra. Phasellus vitae auctor justo. Donec ac vestibulum magna. Cras enim magna, feugiat ut sollicitudin sit amet, dapibus sed
      leo. Phasellus vitae condimentum urna, vitae sodales nunc. Vestibulum sed nisl at leo mollis molestie. Curabitur at nulla sit amet metus finibus commodo eu quis odio. Mauris ut eros elementum, congue eros in, euismod quam. Donec quis dui quis nunc
      elementum hendrerit. Suspendisse tristique, est feugiat imperdiet dictum, augue tortor convallis mauris, at euismod urna mauris in lorem. Vestibulum id arcu at enim lacinia dictum. Ut interdum interdum dui vitae varius. Etiam bibendum diam nec elit
      sagittis consequat. Nulla eleifend dictum nisl, ac pellentesque erat scelerisque in. Praesent consequat porta mauris, ut fermentum turpis dictum et. </p>

</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="generate()" class="btn">Export here</a>
```

Comment: The unique option that works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77853463/2415632

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the `<h1>` element by giving it an `id` like: `<h1 id="title">` and write the following code for getting the title with JavaScript:

```
let titleElement = document.getElementById('title');
let title = titleElement.innerText;
```

With jQuery you can get the title like:

```
let title = $('#title').text(); // Much shorter
```

And for the background image you could write the following with JavaScript:

```
let banner = document.getElementsByClassName("banner");
let bannerStyle = bannerElement.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(banner , false);
let bannerBackGroundUrl = bannerStyle.backgroundImage.slice(4, -1).replace(/"/g, "");
```

With Jquery you could get the background image url with:

```
let backGroundImgUrl = $('.banner').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(['"](.+)['"]\)/, '$1');
```

**Update based on comment**

Try to add the following property `useCORS: true` to the `html2canvas` object like:

```
 html2canvas: {
     scale: 2,
     logging: true,
     dpi: 192,
     letterRendering: true,
     useCORS: true
  }

<div id="main-content-para">
    <div class="banner">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h1>
    </div>
```

Comment: but how can I pass the title and backGroundImgUrl to html2pdf?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Have you tested your answer? i have checked but not working

Comment: I am still confused, how can I pass the title and backGroundImgUrl to html2pdf?

Comment: You are welcome. Please add the `banner` element within the `main-content-para` element. I have updated my answer.

Comment: That is the issue, I can't add banner inside main-content-para because it's copy my layout and paste in the pdf... same I have mention in the question

Comment: Check this link https://imgur.com/fMubfi1 if I add a banner inside my main-content-para then it's showing like this... This is my actual content. This is the reason I asked the question, of how to add the title and background separately.

Comment: Any more help in this?